# Palm detection not working in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: touchpad, xinput

I have just installed Ubuntu 16.04 and tried to enable palm detection by doing

`xinput set-prop "SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad" "Synaptics Palm Dimensions" 5 5
xinput set-prop "SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad" "Synaptics Palm Detection" 1`

But it seems it is not working. How could I make palm detection work?

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable the detection first then set the dimensions. Just reverse your commands.

```
xinput set-prop "SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad" "Synaptics Palm Detection" 1
xinput set-prop "SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad" "Synaptics Palm Dimensions" 5 5
```

Comment: It doesn't work

Comment: Ziyang Chen's did work for me with a Dell XPS 15 (DLL07BE:01 06CB:7A13 Touchpad Can you post the output from the "xinput" command?

Answer (score 0):

Try using "synclient" from the synaptics tool

synclient -l  will list the parameters
palm detection min width could be lowered, for instance I lowered it from 10 to 5.
synclient PalmMinWidth=5

Comment: It doesn't work for me. I guess one needs `synclient PalmDetect=1` too. It doesn't work for me in either case.